# Mount NextJS project to shadow DOM

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shadow-dom

I made a widget with NextJS which I want to be able to use on different websites.

In order to be able to use some scroll functionality I need to mount my widget into shadow-dom.

I found some tutorials online how it is done with React but I am unsure how I can do this with my NextJS project.